# What happens if multiple request's comes to a single servlet..?

Tags: servlets

Can anybody answer me in this issue..

What happens if multiple request's comes to a single servlet..?

i.e. Servlet will contains all the methods init(), service() and destroy() after destroy method without restarting the server i need to make call to the same servlet, then what happens to the servlet whether it will creates a new instance or i need to restart before calling the same servlet...

Thanks...

Comment: It's absolutely unclear to me what you're asking here? I sounds like you manually called the Servlet's `destroy` method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do servlets work? Instantiation, session variables and multithreading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How and when the servlet instances are created is upto the container. Unless if specified as load-on-startup, which ensures the servlet instance is created on starting of the application.

Only thing we can specify is whether the servlet is ***javax.servlet.SingleThreadModel*** or not. If it is SingleThreaded the container will ensure that one servlet instance is used by one request/thread at any point of time.

Comment: Let me explain the flow... A servlet is having the init(), service() and destroy() which we are calling manually. When the request comes from the browser it will preocesses the servlet methods and gives the response back to the console. Then without restarting the server if you make an another request to the same servlet then what will happen..? whether it will creates a new instance or it will uses the same instance? or else is it possible to make a new request to the same servlet without restarting the server?

Comment: you are not supposed to call any of init(), service() and destroy() methods manually? how are u calling them? from where are u calling them?

Comment: Hello...calling in the sense am not calling that methods in another class or method i had implemented the servlet lifecycle in one servlet..and i am sending request from one Html and after getting the response to the console again i am sending a new request to the same what happens?

Comment: I got your point now. It is upto the container to decide how many servlet instance to be created. Usually whenever a request comes, service() method of the same instance will be called. Unless you implement javax.servlet.SingleThreadModel interface which is a special case.

Comment: Will it creates a new instance for the new request or it will reuses the same instance? and what happens if we use the same in SingleThreadModel interface can u elaborate...

Comment: It will use the same instance.

Comment: javax.servlet.SingleThreadModel is used to tell the container that no two threads should use the same instance at any point of time. For this reason, container might pool instances and give different servlet instance for concurrent requests.